# Как автоматически создать нужное количество значений в context в docxtpl исходя из словаря

Tags: python, list, context, docxtpl

Помогите как сделать. Есть список людей в txt. Есть шаблон в word с элементами {{тут  должен встать текст из словаря}}. Но количество людей разное всегда. Как создать автоматом context  столько раз сколько в словаре значений.
Вот код.

```
my_list1 = open("111.txt", encoding= 'utf-8').readlines()
print (my_list1)
d = {}
for index, value in enumerate(my_list1):
    d[index] = value

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
doc = DocxTemplate("qwerty.docx")
context = {}
doc.render(context)
doc.save("client100.docx")
```

Вот тут context = {   } нужно создать то количество значений "user1" : d[1] и так далее сколько находиться в словаре значений.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял:

```py
context = {f"user{key}": val for key,val in d.items()}
```

Но не проще ли сразу в `d` нужный словарь сделать:

```
for index, value in enumerate(my_list1):
    d[f'user{index}'] = value

context = d
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.  Буду пробовать.  Как разберусь дам обратную связь.  Ответить на вопрос: - "Но не проще ли сразу в d нужный словарь сделать" пока не готов.  Только изучаю Python а ранее вообще с языками не был знаком.

Comment: {f"user{key}": val for key,val in d.items()} Все работает как надо только мне бы эту строчку расшифровать что бы я понимал как работает.